# How to get the value of an array input form where the input form is only selected in the datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, input

Form input values cannot appear according to the row selected in the datatable

Here's what I tried :

```
let selRows = allocationTable.rows({
        selected: true
      }).data();
```

```
let data = [];
```

```
let qty_allocation = $("input[name='qty_allocation[]']")
        .map(function() {
          return $(this).val();
        }).get();
```

```
$.each(selRows, function(x, item) {
        data.push({
          "idbarcode": item.idbarcode,
          "idmain": item.idmain,
          "qty_allocation": qty_allocation
 });
});
```

I want the values from the input form to be pushed in the right order.
like :
qty_allocation (inputted from the form) : example 20 (first input), 30 (second input)

then:
{idbarcode : 123, idmain : 1,  qty_allocation : 20},
{idbarcode : 123, idmain : 1,  qty_allocation : 30}, etc